# Stuck on my Java homework -- Hangman game with StringBuilder -- help?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

*NOTE: I AM NOT ASKING YOU TO DO MY HOMEWORK. I am just stuck.

I am designing a Hangman class right now. Apparently, we need three StringBuilders (a) one to display hyphens: `"--------"` the length of the word, b) one to display correct letters guessed: `"--a--e---"`, and finally c) another one that is essentially the opposite of b (guessed letters replaced by hyphens and unguessed letters revealed). The purpose of c) is to see if there are any matches during guessing.

My biggest problem is I can't find many practical StringBuilder examples on Google, namely my biggest issue is where can/should I instantiate the three StringBuilders in the Hangman class?

thanks...

Comment: Do you really need 3 variables for this? You could as well use one StringBuilder and keep changing the characters as and when the player guesses.

Comment: [StringBuilder Examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0100__String/UseStringBuildertoreverseastring.htm)

Comment: Please do not use the homework tag

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Seems like he should use it, care to explain? :)

Comment: @willCode http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions  Do this by mentioning that it is homework in the question text; the homework tag, like other so-called "meta" tags, is now discouraged.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - well the wiki for the homework tag says nothing about it

Comment: @willCode great to know, perhaps teh wiki should be updated

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing here that you have a Hangman class which works as a model that does three things (relevant for this) which is:

- Gives you a string with one - for each character in the word to guess
- Gives you a string which shows the correctly guessed characters in the right position
- Gives you a string which shows which characters have been used

These are all dependent on the state of the model which would be

- the word
- characters guessed

Based on that I'd say that you should have three methods that return Strings and in each of those methods you create a new StringBuilder instance. Building a string is separate from the state just to make it clear why I disagree with Computerish.

StringBuilder is a more efficient way to build up strings then just using concatenation, but it is easy to use. You start with creating an instance of it.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

Then you build up the String by appending Strings or chars (or other things):

```
builder.append('-');
builder.append('w');
```

When you are done you construct a String instance from the StringBuilder:

```
String string = builder.toString();
```

and you end up with "-w" which is a rather boring example.

Comment: see comments posted under Computerish's comment for specifics as to why it's so spot on lol

Comment: @votezdlr - Thanks, I could go on but hopefully you have enough to continue :)

Comment: So for...

private String word; // instance variable declared earlier before Constructor.

public String word() {       // the guessed word
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(word); // this?
}

or what? I'm sorry maybe it's too early or something but I can't seem to come up with a good strategy for tackling this problem.

Comment: @votezdlr - You don't have to create the StringBuilders in your constructor. Don't create them until you actually need them in the method they are used. Think of methods as verbs, something that your class can do. For instance buildGuessedLettersString, buildWordToGuessString etc. In these methods you use a StringBuilder to build up the correct Strings

Answer (score 0):

A short example:

```
StringBuilder helloWorldBuilder = new StringBuilder();
helloWorldBuilder.append("Hello");
helloWorldBuilder.append(" ");
helloWorldBuilder.append("World");
helloWorldBuilder.append("!");
String helloWorld = helloWorldBuilder.toString();
```

And yes, you can create as many `StringBuilder` objects as you like (assuming you have an unlimited heap, but practically spoken: "as many as you like" which is bigger then 3 :-) )

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a StringBuilder is to build a string right before it is consumed.  They should be created fresh each time (this is good practice for the tougher problems that lie ahead).  So instead of thinking about the stringbuilder class, think instead of how to build the string you need.  Assuming you are storing the correct guesses in a char array, you can have three methods that build the string as needed.  In one of those cases you shouldn't need a StringBuilder at all.

Your `ToBlankFormat` method could look like this:

```
public String toBlankFormat()
{
    char[] format = new char[answer.length()];
    Arrays.fill(format, '-');
    return new String(format);
}
```

Essentially, to use a StringBuilder all you do is append strings, characters, etc. and then call the `ToString()` method.  An example would look like this:

```
public String example()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Hello"); // initial value

    if (addSpaces)
    {
        builder.append(" ");
    }

    builder.append("World");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The three StringBuilders should be instance variables of your class. You can instantiate them in your class constructor or you can instantiate them when you choose the word that is being guessed.

Comment: I have to disagree here. They could be instance variables, but saying that they should is going to far.

Comment: The template for the Hangman class (provided by the CS lab here at wonderful University) included the following class constructor:

Comment: and a method for 'word' too:

public String word()....

srry for multiple post there, still getting used to StackOverflow interface lol. But thanks for such prompt response guys!

Comment: Using StringBuilders or StringBuffers as instance variables can lend themselves to bad mojo when you deal with more complex problems, such as race conditions and other concurrency problems.  Their intent is for creating complex strings as needed, and do not pose a major strain on the garbage collector.  In short, it's just a bad practice.  StringBuilders are for representing state, not for keeping it.

Comment: Certainly there are many ways to do this. In my experience in computer science classes the wording of the question would indicate that the teacher is looking for three `StringBuilders` as instance variables. That said, your teacher may be looking for something different than mine was.